# IDE/Hosting issues w/ Meteor/WebStorm/Cloud9

Tags: windows, ubuntu, meteor, webstorm

My next work project is going to be using the Meteor framework. Our team recently got licensed to use WebStorm IDE, which has been our favorite up until this point. so we were planning on continuing the project with it.

That is, until it was time to install it. Then we found out that the Windows version of Meteor is only partially finished, and all of our development PC's are windows based.

So we were considering as a work-around for this, we may use Cloud9 as our development IDE, as it supports Meteor. The sharing functions may help our team productivity a bit as well.

But this has some problems...

First, we just invested in WebStorm, so we would ideally like to use it as our primary IDE. But I do not know how we would be able to work with WebStorm if we can not run an up to date version of Meteor on our windows systems?

Second, I'm not sure if it's even possible to use Cloud9 as the development IDE, but then move the C9 project over to our Ubuntu server for hosting when it is time to go live?

Third, even if we could deploy to our Ubuntu server after C9, we plan on many updates to our live application after deployment. I'm not sure if there would be issues with this if our development is on C9 and deployment on a completely different server.

So I'm wondering if anyone has a potential solution for these issues? Is there any way for us to work with Meteor on our live Ubuntu server, or Cloud9, from WebStorm on our Windows systems? Or any way we could integrate Cloud9 and WebStorm together for the best of both worlds? Or any way we could use a Linux emulator or something to allow us to use Meteor on our local windows system, without making it difficult for multiple developers to work on the project at the same time?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm sorry to say that I think your question reflects huge lack of prior research and investigation. @dan-dascalescu is right, you should develop on windows. Meteor does not have blocking issues on Windows and it is in active development, so whatever problem you see today, will probably have been fixed tomorrow. Also, your questions regarding workflow are just standard development, building, deployment lifecycle questions that have numerous answers that can potentially work just as good for you. So, develop on windows, and investigate further building/deployment options that are far too many.

Comment: @Serkan: I did spend a lot of time researching, I was just not aware that the windows port was working so well. Nothing on the page for the development version of Meteor for Windows indicates that it is that far along. On the topic of C9 questions, we have not used their IDE before, and according to their documentation deploying works differently compared to if you develop it locally, so that's why the questions. "Standard development" is not so standard if you are using a cloud-based solution for the first time.

Comment: @SerkanDurusoy: while to us who are knowledgeable of the Meteor ecosystem, it may seem that the question could've been researched online, it's sometimes helpful to bring together the various bits of pieces under a "state of Meteor and WebStorm under Windows" type of writeup.

Comment: That's right, I think I was being overprotective and did not mean to be offending. I sincerely apologize. On another note, I'd suggest looking into nitrous.io for remote development as an alternative. They have a desktop *syncing* app that let's you develop locally as well. Might be a saver in situations where Meteor does not behave normally on Windows.

Comment: @Serkan: Thanks for the suggestion! I will give the windows preview a go for now and if I have problems will check out nitrous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Windows port of Meteor](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Preview-of-Meteor-on-Windows) actually is working quite well; the only major issue is that mobile development doesn't work. That is going to be fixed in Meteor 1.1 anyway, whose primary goal is to get Windows support up to that of Linux and Mac OS X.

As [the user who initially pushed for Webstorm to add Meteor support back in October 2012](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-6264), I'd recommend starting with Webstorm and Meteor on Windows right away, unless you need mobile development. In that case, you need native *nix machine (an Ubuntu VM on Windows won't be able to run the Android emulator, for example).

WebStorm also supports server-side Meteor debugging, and they're pretty responsive when it comes to fixing bugs you report on YouTrack. See for example https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-13490

Comment: Sounds great! I knew of the debugging for Meteor - I tried the win.meteor.com solution. But it was very outdated and much of the documentation was not working so I gave up on that. I just was not aware that WebStorm already works with the preview for windows, and that the preview was so far along in development. Not too worried about mobile development (yet) browsers will be fine for now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

With Cloud9, you cannot currently SSH into a workspace you have, so a hybrid Webstorm/Cloud9 situation might not be doable at this point.

As for deploying your stuff from Cloud9, that is very doable. There's some documentation here about that: https://docs.c9.io/v1.0/docs/deploying-via-the-command-line

Comment: That link looks like it's talking about deploying to cloud based servers. I would like to add the app to an existing Ubuntu server we already own. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, I'd say so. I've seen other people do this with FTP, but I prefer to use Git. Will one of those work or do you have something else in mind?